# What's the best way to check if a repository object in GitHub's GraphQL Library uses GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-api, github-graphql

I know that I can use the Deployments field of a GitHub GraphQL Repository object to check if the repository uses GitHub pages - but if a repository has multiple deployments strategies (if that's even possible?), one might have to paginate through the deployments connection for each repository to check. I wonder if there's a simpler way I'm not thinking of?